# Threaded python socket server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I have a `Multihtreaded` Server with python that can handle clients request, but i have a problem with this.
In my `Server Class`  I have a `start` function that start listening to clients like this:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, clients={}):
        self.clients = clients
        self.ip = 'localhost'
        self.port = ****
        self.pattern = '(C\d)'


def start(self):
    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port))
    self.s.listen(10)
    while 1:
        clientsock, addr = self.s.accept()
        print ('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.handler, (clientsock, addr))
def handler(self, clientsock, addr):
    data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
    print ('Data : ' + repr(data))
    data = data.decode("UTF-8")
    result = re.match(self.pattern, data)
    print (data)
    if(result):
        self.registerClient(clientsock, data)
    if(data == "Exit"):
        self.exitClient(clientsock)
def server_response(self, message, flag, err):
    if(flag):
        res = message.encode('utf-8')
        return res
    else:
        res = message.encode('utf-8')+ "[ ".encode('utf-8')+err.encode('utf-8')+ " ]".encode('utf-8')
        return res

def registerClient(self, clientsock, data):
    if(data in self.clients):
        err = "Error : Client Name Exist!"
        clientsock.send(self.server_response('Reg#NOK#', 0, err))
        clientsock.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    self.clients[clientsock] = data
    clientsock.send(self.server_response('Reg#OK', 1, ''))
def exitClient(self, clientsock):
    try:
        f = self.clients.pop(clientsock)
        clientsock.send(self.server_response('BYE#OK', 1, ''))
        clientsock.close() 
    except KeyError:
        err = "Error : Client Doesn't Connected To Server!"
        clientsock.send(self.server_response('BYE#NOK#', 0, err))
        clientsock.close()
        sys.exit(1)
```

And this is my `client Class`:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ip = '127.0.0.1'
        self.next_client = None
        self.s = ""
        try:
            self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except:
            print ('Reg#NOK#[ ' + msg[1] + ' ]')
            sys.exit()
def register(self, server):
    self.s.connect((server.ip, server.port))
    message = self.name
    try:
        self.s.sendall(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
    except (socket.error):
        print ('Send Failed')
        sys.exit()

    reply = self.s.recv(4096)
    print ("Respose From Server : " + reply.decode("utf-8") )
def exitFromServer(self, server):
    message = "Exit".encode('utf-8')
    try:
        a = self.s.sendall(message)
    except (socket.error):
        print ('Send Failed')
        sys.exit()

    reply = self.s.recv(4096)
```

And this is the main file:

```
from server import *
from client import *
import _thread

a = Server()
_thread.start_new_thread(a.start, ())
b = Client("C1")
b.register(a)
b.exitFromServer(a)
```

As you can see when start function from `Server class` called there is no thread that can handle create `Client` , I mean when I use start function like this with out thread there is no way that program can go ahead in main file , I know I should use another thread here but where and how, I use `Python 3.4`, Thanks for helping me.

**Edit**

the Problem with start was Solved , Thanks from tdelaney, 
but when I run this only the `register` function works and `exitFromServer` dont do anything can you tell me where is the problem.the program dosent do anything after execute `register` function and it seems that its wating for something.

Comment: `_thread.start_new_thread(a.start)` should do it.

Comment: @tdelaney where?? in __init__ function or where??

Comment: In main, replace `a.start()` with `_thread.start_new_thread(a.start)`.

Comment: @tdelaney It's correct but there is another bug, see edit2

Comment: Your example code doesn't include the server handler so I'm not sure what the explanation is. Can you post it... or an abbreviated version that just handles the IO if its big and complex? There isn't any feedback on the client side so it might have worked. Consider that this is a streaming protocol so the server needs to know when messages end. A common option is to use something like `\n` or a nul to terminate requests.

Comment: @tdelaney i think server handler is handle function, this is whole code , u mean the problem is with message and server can't understand end of messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Server Class` I must add another `while True` loop  after `handler` function cause it shuould do all client request till client has request:

```
def handler(self, clientsock, addr):
    while 1:
        data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
        print ('Data : ' + repr(data))
        data = data.decode("UTF-8")
        result = re.match(self.pattern, data)
        if(result):
            self.registerClient(clientsock, data)
        if(data == "Exit"):
            self.exitClient(clientsock)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean?

```
import threading
from server import *
from client import *

global a
a = Server()
def sServer():
    global a
    a.start()

def cClient():
    global a
    b = Client("C1")
    b.register(a)


s = threading.Thread(name='server', target=sServer)
c = threading.Thread(name='client', target=cClient)

s.start()
c.start()
```

Comment: This dosent work too, if i use exitFromServer in cClient dosent work and if i add another threading for exitFromSever, it can be executed earlier than register thread and rise error